# In Ember, can services have computed properties?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

It appears from the API that [services](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Service.html) in Ember extends the main [Ember object](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html) base class, which implements the observable class, but when I define a property in my Ember service with `.property`, my tests fail with `undefined is not a function`.

Comment: can you throw up the code you have either here or on JSBIN

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that, yes, Ember services can have computed properties, and that this bug came from something else. In my tests I was calling `service.numberOfThings()` and after appending `.property()` to `numberOfThings: function(){...}` I needed to change the test code to `service.get('numberOfThings');`